# Grails how to get the original request uri

Tags: grails

**request.forwarURI** gives me the uri grails resolved to.

```
 myapp/controller/action
```

**request.requestURI** gives me some intermediate uri with '.dispatch' on the end and is neither the original request path nor the resolved one.

```
myapp/grails/controller/action.dispatch
```

How can I get the the original request uri as it was submitted?

```
  myapp/controller/action/_hey/_where/_did/_i/_go.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
request.getHeader( 'referer' )
```